# Rails, choosing option in drop-down filters values in second drop-down

Tags: forms, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create some pages in my rails app, using bits and pieces of what I've learned from some Railscasts.  My environment is as follows:

Rails 3.2.13

ruby 1.9.3p448

Using the chosen gem

Database SQLite

When I want to create a new profile, I would visit localhost:3000/profiles/new.
There I have a text box for my profile called Name.  Next I have a drop-down
where the use can choose what profile type - Admin, Editor or User.  Once an
option is selected, another drop-down becomes visible - Traits.  The user can 
then choose 1 or many traits.

For each profile type (Admin, Editor, User) there are different traits.  So the
Traits model has fields name and trait_type where trait_type would have a value
of either Admin, Editor or User.

I'm having trouble coding the view, assuming I should code there, but maybe I
should be in a controller, getting the Traits drop-down to display only say
Admin traits if I choose a profile type of Admin.

Can someone please give me a nudge in a positive direction?  Please keep in mind
that I'm new to this.  Hope I am providing enough, and not too much information.

Note:  The console.log entries in my profiles.js.coffee file is temporary, just
so I can see what is going on.

Thanks,

HoGi

```
-------------------------------------------------
/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
-------------------------------------------------
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require chosen-jquery
    //= require_tree .
-------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------
/app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js.coffee
-------------------------------------------------
jQuery ->
  $('#profile_trait_ids').chosen()

jQuery ->
  $('#profile_trait_ids').parent().hide()
  prof_types = $('#profile_prof_type').html()
  console.log(prof_types)
  $('#profile_prof_type').change ->
    prof_type = $('#profile_prof_type :selected').text()
    console.log(prof_type)
    $('#profile_trait_ids').parent().show()
-------------------------------------------------  


-------------------------------------------------
/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
-------------------------------------------------
*= require_self
 *= require chosen
 *= require_tree .
 */
-------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------
/app/models/profile.rb
-------------------------------------------------
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :name, :prof_type, :trait_ids

  has_many :traitships
  has_many :traits, through: :traitships

  PROFILE_TYPES = ["Admin", "Editor", "User"]

end
-------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------
/app/models/trait.rb
-------------------------------------------------
class Trait < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :name, :trait_type

  has_many :traitships
  has_many :profiles, through: :traitships
end
-------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------
/app/models/traitship
-------------------------------------------------
class Traitship < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :profile_id, :traid_id

  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :trait
end
-------------------------------------------------


-------------------------------------------------
/app/views/_form.html.erb
-------------------------------------------------
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <% if @profile.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@profile.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this profile from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @profile.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :prof_type, 'Profile Type' %><br />
    <%= f.select :prof_type, Profile::PROFILE_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a type' %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :trait_ids, "Traits" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_select :trait_ids, Trait.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :active %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :active %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
-------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATED CONTROLLER:
(traits_controller)

```
# GET /traits/:trait_type/trait_options
  # GET /traits/:trait_type/trait_options.json
  def trait_options
    @traits = Trait.order(:name).where("trait_type like ?", params[:trait_type])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # trait_options.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @traits }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1

You should add a new action to your controller (traits_controller) that takes as input one parameter  `profile_type` and returns all `traits` for that `profile_type` as json/xml.

### Part 2

Once you have this ready, You should call this action via ajax on `on_change` event of your `profile_type` dropdown. Use that data received to construct the new `traits` dropdown.

`chosen`, `select2` etc, should make this very easy to accomplish once your part 1 is ready.

**Update**

I have never used `chosen` myself. But looking at its documentation, something like this might work for you

```
$('#profile_type').on('change', function() {
    $("#traits").chosen().change( … );
    $("#traits").trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

This [Railscast (Episode #258)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised?view=asciicast) demonstrates how a `chosen select` is populated using json data

If it is possible to drop `chosen` in favor of `select2`, I highly recommend you do it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  From a high level I understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure how to implement - what files need updating etc.  I have updated the traits_controller and tested that the json is working.  I'll try to post the new changes in the original post, code section.  Can you (or anyone,) provide some more tips/direction?

Comment: I tried getting both chosen and select2 to do what I wanted but with no success.  After re-watching Railscast 258, as well as some other similar episodes, I tried to complete the task using jquery-tokeninput.  I have been successful for the most part.  Now I just have some minor clean up.  The bugger duplicates my token text box if one selects the Type drop-down more than once.  Thank you for you r help and suggestions.  Off to search for a solution to the duplication problem.